# I got a problem with window.history.pushState

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I tried to redirect to another url when visiter click back from browser, I used the code bellow and put it in single.php ( I only want the code work on post ). The code work great but it clear the **Adword id** after **/gclid=**

Jquery

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
   window.history.pushState(null, null, './');
      $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      location.href = "/";
   });
<script>
```

Comment: Do you want for any specific browser or for all browser?

Comment: for all browser my bro!

Answer (score 0):

For browser back event you use the below code:

Currently, I have set the redirection to google.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        if ( window.history && window.history.pushState ) {
            window.history.pushState('', null, './');
            jQuery(window).on('popstate', function() {
                // alert('Back button was pressed.');
                document.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Note: if you need to add this code in .JS file then please ignore the `<script>` tag.